# If you get polymorph any object'ed into something with a different racial alignment, does your alignment change?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment, polymorph

Let's take a neutral character.

If it is hit with *Polymorph Any Object* and is turned into a LG dragon, does their alignment change to LG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the Rules As Written: no.  *Polymorph Any Object* acts like *greater polymorph* which acts like *beast shape*.  *Beast shape* causes the character to take on a new form but does not affect their mind.

However someone might make a house rule along these lines. The official rules don't give us much guidance on how, specifically, creatures with an alignment get "drawn to that alignment" as they develop. I can imagine a DM might rule that creatures with a LG alignment are biologically predisposed to Law and Good, and that a character who spends a lot of time as such a creature might gradually, eventually become LG themselves.

Answer (score 4):

There are no "*LG  Dragon*" or "*Lawful Good Dragon*" creature on the bestiaries, there are dragons that are normally of Lawful Good alignment.

You cannot turn into creatures of a specific alignment or into specific creatures, because that is their alignment from their personality, not their form, and you assume *their form*, not their personalities.

Your aligment is not affected in any way by any of the (currently) existing [polymorph subschool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation) spells.

> Unless otherwise noted, polymorph spells cannot be used to change into specific individuals.